Logistic regression failing to generate coefficents for categorical covariate
I have an binary target variable representing the generation of a new sales opportunity (1) or the failure of the generation (0). An opportunity can happen to have a marketing touchpoint in the previous 60 days (mkt_flag=1) or happen without a marketing touchpoint (0). A marketing touchpoint can be "productive" in generating an opp for maximum 60 days from its date. Meaning that we can have the following combinations of target variable and predictor: Opp yes + Mkt yes. Opp no + Mkt yes. Opp yes + Mkt no. HOWEVER: there are records for Opp no + Mkt no. The frequency table is the following:
.
However, when trying to model in SAS the opportunity target including the MKT flag variable, I'm getting a "0" estimate for the mkt flag variable, probably due to the distribution of the mkt variable over the target. Any idea about situation like these of unbalanced covariate distribution could be modeled alternative? The purpose is to estimate the association of the mkt flag variable to the opp target.

This happens because mkt = 0 predicts success perfectly, so there is complete separation, and the maximum likelihood estimates tend to infinity (become inestimable).
You need a firthlogit:
. #delimit;
delimiter now ;
. clear;

. input byte(opp mkt) long n;

          opp       mkt             n
  1. 1 0 25408;
  2. 0 1 1985525;
  3. 1 1 6555;
  4. end;

. firthlogit opp i.mkt [fweight = n], nolog;

                                                     Number of obs = 2,017,488
                                                     Wald chi2(1)  =    136.86
Penalized log likelihood = -44025.646                Prob > chi2   =    0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         opp | Coefficient  Std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       1.mkt |  -16.54672   1.414392   -11.70   0.000    -19.31888   -13.77457
       _cons |   10.83339   1.414337     7.66   0.000     8.061339    13.60544
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. margins mkt, expression(invlogit(predict(xb))) post;

Adjusted predictions                                 Number of obs = 2,017,488
Model VCE: OIM

Expression: invlogit(predict(xb))

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         mkt |
          0  |   .9999803   .0000279  3.6e+04   0.000     .9999256    1.000035
          1  |   .0032908   .0000406    81.10   0.000     .0032113    .0033703
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

.  // coeflegend;
> lincom (_b[1.mkt] - _b[0bn.mkt]);

 ( 1)  - 0bn.mkt + 1.mkt = 0

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             | Coefficient  Std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         (1) |  -.9966895   .0000492 -2.0e+04   0.000     -.996786    -.996593
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. logit opp i.mkt [fweight = n], nolog;
note: 0.mkt != 0 predicts success perfectly;
      0.mkt omitted and 1 obs not used.

note: 1.mkt omitted because of collinearity.

Logistic regression                                  Number of obs = 1,992,080
                                                     LR chi2(0)    =      0.00
                                                     Prob > chi2   =         .
Log likelihood = -44017.214                          Pseudo R2     =    0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         opp | Coefficient  Std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         mkt |
          0  |          0  (empty)
          1  |          0  (omitted)
             |
       _cons |  -5.713411   .0123717  -461.81   0.000    -5.737659   -5.689162
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The firthlogit average marginal effect is $-.9966895 \approx -1$, so marketing appears to be rather harmful. This is the average change in the probability of success in the estimation sample.
I suspect some sort of selection is going on, but it's hard to give advice without knowing how marketing is assigned to potential customers. Presumably, marketing efforts are not wasted on those who are expected to respond favorably, so it's not a randomized control group.
The two references are:

Firth, D. 1993. Bias reduction of maximum likelihood estimates. Biometrika 80:27-38.
Heinze, G. and Schemper, M. 2002. A solution to the problem of separation in logistic regression. Statistics in Medicine 21:2409-19.


On the assignation side, all the accounts are from groups that are heavily targeted by marketing for their size, so one can assume same treatment assignation within marketing for all the accounts analyzed (and yes, marketing target also the one who respond favorably because being b2b opportunities, seeding is important also in "friendly" accounts for marketing to "expect" to boost new opportunities as possible)

@davidecortellino Getting off topic here, but if you use a lead scoring system for targeting, then that score can be used in a (propensity score) matching or regression discontinuity analysis.

You are dealing with an issue of quasi-complete separation. This occurs when the outcome variable is perfectly or almost perfectly predicted by a predictor variable. You could try a form of regularized logistic regression to help handle this, but if your focus is on interpretation of the association you may be better off using a different technique. Look into the Phi coefficient for two binary variables.
